# if $n^2+1$ is composite, then $n!+n^2+1$ is composite

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove if $n^2+1$ is composite, then $n!+n^2+1$ is composite
I try to let $n^2+1$ = ad for some a,d $\in$ Z, but I find it doesn't work 
Just want to know the main idea for this problem

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** If $n^2+1=ad$ show that $a \leq n$ or $d \leq n$.

Comment: Yes. An even better hint would have been to say that $n^2+1$ is not a square.